# How to auto add id on form?

Tags: laravel

Add id manually looks like this

```
{!! Form::text('email', null, ['id' => 'email', 'class' => 'active']) !!}
```

How to auto add id?

Any example to use macro?

Comment: What are the ids you want to add ? Are they numbers,strings? what is their pattern?

Comment: Immediate thoughts. Extend the Form Builder and with all the input you want to render, set properties and call the parent method. Change the facade to point at yours.

Comment: @Peyman.H I want to make same with attribute name

Comment: @Chris can u help me with example, and where I must add?

Answer (score 0):

Create your new FromBuilder Class :

```
class MyFormBuilder extends \Collective\Html\FormBuilder /** Original Form Builder*/{

    // Override the text function
    public function text($name, $value = null, $options = []){

        // If the ID is not explicitly defined in the call
        if(!isset($options['id'])){

            // Set ID equal to the name
            $options['id'] = $name;

        }

        // Call the original text function with the new ID set
        parent::text($name,$value,$options);
    }

}
```

Then Create a new Service Provider

```
<?php

namespace My\Provider\Space;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyHtmlServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerHtmlBuilder();

        $this->registerFormBuilder();

        $this->app->alias('html', 'Collective\Html\HtmlBuilder');
        $this->app->alias('form', 'My\Class\Space\MyFormBuilder');
    }

    /**
     * Register the HTML builder instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerHtmlBuilder()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('html', function ($app) {
            return new \Collective\Html\HtmlBuilder($app['url'], $app['view']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the form builder instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerFormBuilder()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('form', function ($app) {
            $form = new \My\Class\Space\MyFormBuilder($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['view'], $app['session.store']->getToken());

            return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return ['html', 'form', 'Collective\Html\HtmlBuilder', 'My\Class\Space\FormBuilder'];
    }
}
```

Then update your config/app.php file and do:

1. Remove The old \Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class from the service providers array
2. Add Your new Service provider in it's place.

A basic explanation of what this does:

A. You move the service provider for the HTML helpers to your own service provider where you register your MyBuilder

B. Next time you call \Form that service provider will point it to your builder.

Check out the vendor files for collective to make sure you get all the variables in the function definitions.

Just filter out any namespace errors etc. as I have not completely tested them all.